# Function for calculating degree of latitude from radius

Tags: c#, trigonometry

I know it's high school math, but its doing my head in. Think of the system as a view of the Earth from above the north pole. You have the equator at the edge, that's got a defined radius. Using that defined radius and the radius of an internal circle, how can I find the latitude of this internal circle?

Hope I made sense, I'm sure it's bloody simple!
Thanks

EDIT: I don't need code, just a simple formula. I'm just using the Earth as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat the earth as a perfect sphere, then:

```
Math.Cos(latitudeInRadians) = radiusOfInterest / radiusOfEquator;
```

So the angle (in radians) is:

```
latitudeInRadians = Math.Acos(radiusOfInterest / radiusOfEquator);
```

Then you just need to convert this into degrees:

```
latitudeInDegrees = 180.0 * latitudeInRadians / Math.PI;
```

Edit: Doh! conversion wrong way round.

Comment: The conversion to degrees is a bit suss